# Unit test won't run: process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm making unit tests to test an algorithm I have written, unfortunately these tests won't even run because of this error:

> [10-6-2018 00:12:00 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:06,5685302) ==========
>   [10-6-2018 00:12:04 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>   [10-6-2018 00:12:09 Error] The active test run was aborted. Reason: Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

These are all Unit tests I have:

```
namespace AlgoritmeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class AlgoritmeTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAddingWagonToTrain()
        {
            Train train = new Train();
            Wagon wagon = new Wagon(10);

            List<Wagon> expected = new List<Wagon>();
            expected.Add(wagon);

            train.AddWagon(wagon);
            List<Wagon> actual = train.GetWagons();
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Failed to add wagon to train");

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAddingAnimalToWagon()
        {
            Train train = new Train();
            Wagon wagon = new Wagon(10);
            Animal animal = new Animal("Goudvis", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Big);


            List<Animal> expected = new List<Animal>();
            expected.Add(animal);

            wagon.AddAnimal(animal);
            List<Animal> actual = wagon.GetAnimals();

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Failed to add animal to wagon");
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestIfAnimalsAreReturned()
        {
            Animal animal = new Animal();

            Animal goudvis = new Animal("Goudvis", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Big);
            Animal visstick = new Animal("Visstick", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Big);
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(goudvis);
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(new Animal("Potvis", AnimalFood.Plants, AnimalSize.Medium));
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(new Animal("Zalm", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Small));
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(visstick);
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(new Animal("Varkenshaasje", AnimalFood.Plants, AnimalSize.Big));

            List<Animal> expected = new List<Animal>();
            expected.Add(goudvis);
            expected.Add(visstick);

            List<Animal> actual = animal.GetAllBigMeatEaters();

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Failed to get all animals which meet criteria");
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestIfAlgorithmStepWorks()
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            Animal animal = new Animal();

            Wagon wagon = new Wagon(10);
            Wagon wagon2 = new Wagon(10);

            Animal goudvis = new Animal("Goudvis", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Big);
            Animal visstick = new Animal("Visstick", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Big);

            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(goudvis);
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(visstick);
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(new Animal("Potvis", AnimalFood.Plants, AnimalSize.Medium));
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(new Animal("Zalm", AnimalFood.Meat, AnimalSize.Small));
            animal.animalsFromTheCircus.Add(new Animal("Varkenshaasje", AnimalFood.Plants, AnimalSize.Big));

            wagon.AddAnimal(goudvis);
            wagon2.AddAnimal(visstick);

            Train expected = new Train();

            expected.AddWagon(wagon);
            expected.AddWagon(wagon2);



            program.SetUpProgram(animal.animalsFromTheCircus);
            Train actual = program.AddAllMeatEaters();

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Failed to get all animals which meet criteria and place them in train according to alogrithm");
        }
    }
}
```

**Animal.cs**

```
public class Animal
{
    private string animalName;
    private AnimalFood animalFood;
    private AnimalSize animalSize;

    public Animal(string animalName, AnimalFood animalFood, AnimalSize animalSize)
    {
        this.animalName = animalName;
        this.animalFood = animalFood;
        this.animalSize = animalSize;
    }
    public Animal()
    {

    }

    public List<Animal> animalsFromTheCircus = new DataGenerator().GenerateAnimals(100);

    public List<Animal> GetallAnimals()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus;
    }

    public List<Animal> GetAllBigMeatEaters()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Big && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Meat).ToList();
    }
    public List<Animal> GetAllBigMeatEaters(List<Animal> animalsFromTheCircus)
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Big && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Meat).ToList();
    }
    public List<Animal> GetAllSmallMeatEaters()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Small && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Meat).ToList();
    }
    public List<Animal> GetAllBigPlantEaters()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Big && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Plants).ToList();
    }

    public List<Animal> GetAllMediumMeatEaters()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Medium && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Meat).ToList();
    }
    public List<Animal> GetAllMediumPlantEaters()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Medium && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Plants).ToList();
    }

    public List<Animal> GetAllSmallPlantEaters()
    {
        return animalsFromTheCircus.Where(animal => animal.getAnimalSize() == AnimalSize.Small && animal.getAnimalFood() == AnimalFood.Plants).ToList();
    }

    public string getAnimalName()
    {
        return this.animalName;
    }

    public AnimalFood getAnimalFood()
    {
        return this.animalFood;
    }

    public AnimalSize getAnimalSize()
    {
        return this.animalSize;
    }
}
```

**Wagon.cs**

```
   public class Wagon
{
    private List<Animal> animals;
    private int maxSize;

    public Wagon(int maxSize)
    {
        this.animals = new List<Animal>();
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public void AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        this.animals.Add(animal);
    }

    public List<Animal> GetAnimals()
    {
        return this.animals;
    }
}
```

**Train.cs**

```
    public class Train
{
    private List<Wagon> wagons;

    public Train()
    {
        this.wagons = new List<Wagon>();
    }

    public void AddWagon(Wagon wagon)
    {
        this.wagons.Add(wagon);
    }

    public List<Wagon> GetWagons()
    {
        return this.wagons;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my tests, why won't they run?

Comment: Well, because your logic throws it.

Comment: You need to share the train, wagon and animal class code too.

Comment: @eocron what do you mean?

Comment: There are 4 tests. Run one at a time to narrow down which one is the one throwing the error.

Comment: @Nkosi All of them, even when I try to run them separately..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no circular references in the code you have shown, my spidey senses tells me the problem is here

```
public List<Animal> animalsFromTheCircus = new DataGenerator().GenerateAnimals(100);
```

**Update**

Every time you create an animal it generates animals which creates animals, singularity happens. the whole universe gets sucked in

**Update 2**

There is a serious *Separation of Concerns* problem going on here as well,I mean why does the class animal even have a list of animals, not many animals i know have sub animals (well in any normal sense)..

Comment: But that line is only in one test, the other 3 should still run if that was the problem right?

Comment: Excuse me for being stupid, but I'm still not sure why this is the problem? In the first two tests I'm not even creating an animal

Comment: @KevinTinnemans there is no other errors with you code i can see, comment out that line and see if the problem persists

Comment: I agree with @TheGeneral. Kevin, just replace `public List<Animal> animalsFromTheCircus = new DataGenerator().GenerateAnimals(100);` with `public List<Animal> animalsFromTheCircus = new List<Animal>();` things should start working fine.

Comment: Yeah you were totally right, didn't think that through.. the Animal class also shouldn't include a list of all Animals, stupid coding by me

Comment: @KevinTinnemans even the best coders have brain farts, its all good